# How does using log10 correctly calculate the length of a integer?

Tags: math, logarithm

```
int length = (int) floor( log10 (float) number ) + 1;
```

My question is essentially a math question: WHY does taking the log10() of a number, flooring that number, adding 1, and then casting it into an int correctly calculate the length of number?

I really want to know the deep mathematical explanation please!

Comment: What *is* the [log function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) doing? (Note the relation given at the top of the article, then consider the values of 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, etc.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because even though it has some code, it's actually a maths question.

Comment: @RobertDodier I'm not saying it's a bad question, I'm just saying it's off-topic for SO. Maybe it's just my opinion, but the question is not really about programming even though there's some code.

Comment: @YuHao The [basic] use of log/exp should be in a programmer's tool belt .. since it's a very basic question, presented with [pseudo]code in a common use-case, I think it's "OK" here.

Comment: I asked [this relevant question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-decimal-digits-for-a-binary-number) - not a duplicate - on Mathematics a few years back. Strictly speaking, using `log10` doesn't work - at least not using floating point. For a large enough number, the inaccuracy in the logarithm will be sufficient that your result can be out by any number of digits you choose. You can't experience this with `int` though - you'd have to be using a big-integer type.

Comment: Oh my god, this IS a programming question - it's related to many programming things like changing an integer into a character array (which was the inspiration of asking the question), I wanted to have a deeper understanding of how the log function works - and other programmers can definitely benefit from this knowledge! Other programmers could be in the same bucket - they might want to have an intuition of calculating length of a number. This is a common computer programming question!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for a mathematical proof of a mathematical formula; there is no programming involved here.

Comment: Not a explaination, nor a formal proof, but one could "invent" this formula, by sketching graph of this hypothetical function, and noticing that it is shaped a bit like logarithm graph. If you see that, you can try some transformations and voila

Comment: ~10 years later I get a "Famous Question" achievement (for an off-topic question).

Answer (score 23):

For an integer `number` that has `n` digits, it's value is between `10^(n - 1)`(included) and `10^n`, and so `log10(number)` is between `n - 1`(included) and `n`. Then the function `floor` cuts down the fractional part, leaves the result as `n - 1`.  Finally, adding `1` to it gives the number of digits.

Comment: Nice... you claim it's off topic, then answer it... Fun!

Comment: @lornix I still think it's off-topic, but the comments under the question show that some people don't. Also, it's hard to write all these as a comment.

Comment: Like, `FLOOR(LOG10(n) + 1)`.

Answer (score 11):

Consider that a four-digit number *x* is somewhere between `1000 <= x < 10000`.  Taking the log base 10 of all three components gives `3.000 <= log(x, 10) < 4.000`.  Taking the floor (or int) of each component and adding one gives `4 <= int(log(x, 10))+1 <= 4`.

Ignoring round-off error, this gives you the number of digits in *x*.

Comment: I suggest replacing `<= 3.999` (which isn't true for `x >= 9978`) with `< 4.0`.