# Javascript loop either not running or not ending

Tags: javascript, html

I want to start with a large number in a variable, and while it is larger than another number, subtract 100 from the variable. I then want the loop to put the variable in the "demo" paragraph, which should end up being 89. Any help is appreciated.

```js
var x = 789
while x > 100 {
  x = x-100
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: That code throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `while` condition must be wrapped in parentheses.

```js
var x = 789
while (x > 100) {
  x = x-100
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using parenthesis in the while will fix your problem, just a small syntactical error

```
var x = 789
while (x > 100) {
  x = x-100
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
function sub(x){
while(x > 100){
x = x-100
}
return x
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sub(789);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm - ok - I am really really really rusty at programming, but... you want to generate a predetermined static number and place that static number in a static html element programmatically?  WTF man?

```
<p id="demo">89</p>
```

Is your solution.

No Javascript req'd.  Unless you were hoping for a 'countdown' effect which:
1) Wont work with this code.
2) Wont work with corrected code.
3) Would work with a different methodology so fast you wont see it (you would have to introduce 'sleep' timers and so on).

It's been a bad day please don't take a picture.

Comment: In my full code, the variable "x" will not always be the same number, the number 789 was just an example of what it might be.

Comment: My bad twas a bad mood post.  Uh - you have considered simply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371657/how-to-remove-the-most-significant-digit-of-an-int-e-g-from-547-to-47-to-7?rq=1 from what I can see of what you are trying to do I hope?  er - x % 100 would do instead of the while loop?